# What kind of curtain tracks are these / what do I search for when looking for compatible curtains?

Tags: curtain-rail

Just moved into this place that has existing curtain tracks. What kind of curtains do I look for for these specific tracks? Do these tracks have a name?

Looking for a lower cost option.

[image]

Comment: Usually any curtain will fit/attach to any track.  That track should have points/rings/holders to attach curtains to it.  Not sure if they are called curtain hooks/pins, but they fit in the top of curtains to hang from the tracks.

Comment: Take this picture to a home decor shop and ask them there. I think just about any curtain will work, but I'm not sure that you have all the pieces that you need. It seems to me there should be a series of hangers between the two pull rods to actually hang the curtain from. I'm not sure this question is within the scope of DIY/Home Improvement, but I'll leave that decision to others.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I can't quite nail down the name of something like this I always go to the McMaster-Carr website. It's always way too expensive to purchase there, but often times I can figure out better search terms by rummaging through the catalog. Here's what they have on [curtain rails](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/curtain-rails/).